# Can the electronic configurations give any information about the actual structure of the atom?

Tags: orbitals, electronic-configuration, perturbation-theory

The zeroth order wavefunction for an He atom in the ground state is $\psi^0_\text{He}=\psi_{1s}(1)\psi_{1s}(2)$ and hence the electronic configuration $1s^2$. But then we start making purterbations, we are no more talking about the non-interacting electrons as presented in the w.f. $\psi^0_\text{He}$. Hence, the electronic configuration doesn't really tell us about the actual atom, but gives a crude, starting-point-model of it. Same goes for all multi-electron atoms , so can we modify it to represent the actual wavefunctions (like the molecular MOs, they describe the actual molecular structure to a great extent)?

Comment: No electron configuration of atoms is just a book keeping. Nobody knows the micro structure of the atom. Orbitals are not observables.

Answer (score 1):

The basis you used for constructing your ansatz wave function for a helium atom assigns the one-electron hydrogen wave functions to each of the two electrons of helium. By doing this, you neglect the interaction between the two electrons and using only your ansatz to describe your system gives poor quantitative results (some basic spectral patterns can be explained based on the electron configuration). One approach to take the electron correlation into account is to include a term in your trial wave function that depends on the coordinates of both electrons and minimize the energy with respect to one or several parameters in your wave function. This is basically the approach of Hylleraas and in more complicated form still the basis of state-of-the-art quantum mechanical calculations (search for example for correlated Gaussians).

Even when we do not take the electron correlation into account we can get more accurate results by using a large basis of products of hydrogen wave functions as you did. This basis corresponds to the ground state and (in principle) all possible excited states of the atom. In practice, you need to truncate your basis somewhere, but the more states you include, the more accurate your results in general will be. You can now evaluate the terms of your Hamiltonian for all cross terms of your basis functions. This results in a (Hermitian) symmetric matrix that can be diagonalized. The eigenvalues correspond to the energies of your system and the eigenvectors to the character of each of your trial wave functions in your state of interest. Mathematically, perturbing your system results in admixing other electronic states to your unperturbed state. What I just described corresponds to the Heisenberg representation of quantum mechanics and which is very convenient for doing numerical calculations.